# Non normally distributed data for association analysis in SNPassoc package

Tags: r

Can non normally distributed data (assessed by the Shapiro Wilk test) be used in the association(y~x,data=...) test in the SNPassoc package in R? Will it provide reliable results or should I log transform my traits and variables?

I have a data set with 482 observations and Im looking at 10 different traits in coldblooded trotters (e.g.total number of starts, race time, victories, earnings etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manual ( see http://davinci.crg.es/estivill_lab/tools/SNPassoc/SupplementaryMaterial.pdf ) this model does assume normality, so you better do log normalization or square root your data.

However, in practice if your data have minor deviations from normality it won't break most models.